# Transform the integration of the product of two functions to their convolution

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, transformation, convolution

We have indefinite integral of the product of two functions:

$\int f(t) \cdot g(t) dt$

given that $t∈R$, and functions $f(t),g(t)$ defined in the interval $[0,+\infty)$

Is there a transformation that allow write this integral as a convolution, i.e.:

$\int f(t) \cdot g(t) dt = \int_{0}^{t} h(s) ds$

where $h(s)$ - new function of integral transform.

The question is, how to find the $h(s)$?

This is necessary to transform a differential equation into an integral one and solve it using the Laplace transform.

I would be glad to any advice and help.

Comment: Why is your convolution restricted to $[0,t]$ ?

Comment: See, these are details that are helpful to know. Please edit your post with everything to be considered for these functions. Better yet, explain the larger context of an issue you're facing that explains why you want such an object. Comments should not be necessary to pry these out of you.

Comment: Please, see my edit.